# Odd flex items behavior

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Could someone explain to me this strange behavior?

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 500px;
}
.container {
  background: blue;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

a {
  margin-left: 10px;
  background: pink;
  align-self: start;
}
#title {
  font-size: 21px;
  line-height: 28px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="container">
    <a id="title" href="#">Deserunt exercitationem exercitationem.</a>
    <a href="#">Test</a>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <a id="title" href="#">Deserunt autem non voluptatem velit exercitationem.</a>
    <a href="#">Test</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://codepen.io/rgdgu8uz2llu/pen/VwmwjLa

Why is the flex item `#title` in the second row so stretched, while in the first row as I expect? How do I make `#title` width fit to content, as inline?

Is there any way to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Your code works as expected according to its css rules. Add rule `flex: 1` to `#title`.

Comment: you cannot fix this,

Comment: no, you dont understand - i need width of #title in a second row without any additional space at right

Comment: @rgdgu8uz2llu, Do you want to move word "**exercitationem**" to a new line?